# Can't add card view in layout xml

Tags: android, android-cardview

I can't add a card view in my layout xml for some reason. I already changed my build.grandle file to use this extension:

```
dependencies {
    
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

But whenever I try to use  `<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView/>` it can't be found

Answer (score -1):

You need to add **android:enableJetifier=true** to your gradle.properties

Comment: Thanks for answering my question but I added this and still not working